# Lets Encrypt using Certbot fails in kubernetes (works with cert-manager though)

Tags: kubernetes, lets-encrypt, certbot, cert-manager

I have a Kubernetes cluster version 1.15.5 in Azure where I have installed [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/) version v0.14.0

It works fine with automatically issuing lets encrypt certificates against a valid DNS name: **MY_DOMAIN** pointing to the external IP address of the ingress controller.

I would also like to be able to do this same thing using e.g. [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org). I have tried to run certbot on my cluster with:

```
kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 certbot-shell --rm -i --tty --image certbot/certbot:amd64-latest -- -d MY_DOMAIN --manual --preferred-challenges http certonly
```

But it fails with:

```
Create a file containing just this data:

QAPu****-klNq1RBgY

And make it available on your web server at this URL:

http://MY_DOMAIN/.well-known/acme-challenge/QAPu****-klNq1RBgY

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -


Press Enter to Continue
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain MY_DOMAIN
http-01 challenge for MY_DOMAIN
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: MY_DOMAIN
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://MY_DOMAIN/.well-known/acme-challenge/QAPuDTHa****1qlLLOg
   [13.x.x.x]: 404

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
```

So somehow **cert-manager** automatically takes care of creating the file during the challenge and making it available at:

```
http://MY_DOMAIN/.well-known/acme-challenge/QAPu****-klNq1RBgY
```

But I am not sure how I do that when using **certbot** or if there some other way to do this??

Based on below suggestions I have tried to install Kube lego (0.1.2) instead (for legacy 1.8 cluster) but seems to fail with:

```
level=error msg="Error while processing certificate requests: 403 urn:acme:error:unauthorized: Account creation on ACMEv1 is disabled. Please upgrade your ACME client to a version that supports ACMEv2 / RFC 8555. See https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/end-of-life-plan-for-acmev1/88430 for details." context=kubelego
```

So I have tried to upgrade to:

https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory

but then I get:

```
level=error msg="Error while processing certificate requests: Head : unsupported protocol scheme \"\"" context=kubelego
```

I found:

https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego/issues/301

So looks like kube-lego cannot be used with ACME version 2 :-(

Comment: Why would you use certbot at all? Let alone if you already have cert-manager working, which is the correct tool to use.

Comment: I potentially need to issues (Lets Encrypt) certificates on an old Kubernetes cluster where cert-manager cannot be installed - upgrading the cluster is not an option at the moment.

Comment: Why can't you use cert-manager? certbot is not built for kubernetes, if you insist on using it, you'll want to use it in DNS mode. As you noted, the HTTP mapping that cert-manager automates is much harder to do manually :)

Comment: I have not managed to find a version of cert-manager that can be installed on the old cluster (version 1.8.x) https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/2067

Comment: Try kube-lego instead, the thing that cert manager replaced.

Comment: Looks like kube-lego will not work with ACME version 2 -  which is need to use Lets encrypt  - see updated post.

Comment: Might be doomed, sorry. You can look at using a proxy with integrated LE support like Traefik, though it's definitely getting pretty hard to know what still works with 1.8, that was from years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version of the comments: certbot in DNS mode will probably work, HTTP01 will not since you would need to dynamically adjust Ingress settings, which is exactly what cert-manager does. Overall this is a great example of why running a version of Kube from 2.5 years ago is not good.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand. Using certbot with a DNS challenge will require that I actually have permissions to add the preliminary certbot issued token to the DNS TXT field in the DNS server before I can confirm that certbot should proceed with issuing the certificate, right?

Comment: No, it requires you give Certbot automated access to your DNS provider via a plugin.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear what I meant was that the user running certbot needs to be able (have permissions) to add/update records in the DNS for the given hostname?

Comment: Yes, I suppose you could put it that way. A user doesn't run certbot though, it runs continuously as itself. The specifics vary by provider but generally you give it an API key of some kind.